# VMware ESXi and Intel DC3700 (NVMe) Poor Performance Even With Intel's Driver

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage

I'm running VMware ESXi 6.0.0 with the Intel DC3700 800GB.

My VM is running Windows 10 x64 with 8GB RAM and 4CPU Cores. The entire VM is 32GB and sits on the SSD.

I'm using CrystalDiskMark at 1GiB files size and am concerned with Sequential read:

- When I install Windows directly onto the SSD I get read speeds of
  2700MB/s.
- Before I installed VMW-ESX-5.5.0-intel-nvme-1.0e.1.1-2791094 I was getting 800MB/s read.
- Now that I've installed it I still only get 1700MB/s read.

What could I possibly be missing that's causing it to still run slowly?

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcfg-scsidevs -a
vmhba38 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba38                            (0000:00:1f.2) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba39 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba39                            (0000:00:1f.2) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba0  ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba0                             (0000:00:11.4) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba1  ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba1                             (0000:00:1f.2) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba2  intel-nvme        link-n/a  pscsi.vmhba2                            (0000:04:00.0) Intel Corporation DC P3700 AIC
vmhba40 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba40                            (0000:00:1f.2) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba41 pernixgateway     link-n/a  gsan.0430f73826a28                      () Unknown
vmhba32 usb-storage       link-n/a  usb.vmhba32                             () USB
vmhba33 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba33                            (0000:00:11.4) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba34 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba34                            (0000:00:11.4) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba35 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba35                            (0000:00:11.4) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba36 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba36                            (0000:00:1f.2) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
vmhba37 ahci              link-n/a  sata.vmhba37                            (0000:00:1f.2) Intel Corporation Wellsburg AHCI Controller
[root@localhost:~] for a in $(esxcfg-scsidevs -a |awk '{print $2}') ;do vmkload_mod -s $a |grep -i version ;done
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: 1.0e.1.1-1OEM.550.0.0.1391871
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 1.0-3vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
Version: Version 3.0-22vmw, Build: 3029758, Interface: 9.2 Built on: Aug 31 2015
```

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing any tools that I could use to diagnose exactly where the problem lies?

Comment: Just so I follow you, are you using the DC3700 as a data store or something else?

Comment: On ESXi, reads are boosted and reading may not reflect the real speeds. Only practical tests will determine that.